# Did the MDC draw support from former ZAPU voters and politicians?

Tags: zimbabwe

In the late 80s, [Joshua Nkomo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Nkomo)'s former organisation [ZAPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zimbabwe_African_People%27s_Union) was taken over by Mugabe's [ZANU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zimbabwe_African_National_Union). Did the [MDC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Movement_for_Democratic_Change_(prior_to_2005)) draw any former ZAPU politicians in? Did it draw support from the same ethnic groups and areas in elections?

Comment: Migrated from Politics.SE to History.SE on request of the author. I hope "late 80s" isn't too recent to be considered history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

In the 1980s, the Ndebele minority that was so mistreated by Shona-controlled ZANU-PF supported the ZAPU, and "...[there has always been a strong contingent of Ndebele in the senior ranks of the MDC.](http://minorityrights.org/minorities/ndebele/)" More recently, MDC Chairman Morgan Tsvangirai has spoken forcefully in Matabeleland, the Ndebele homeland, against the ZANU-PF violence. The MDC and its offshoot MDC-T have continued to control Bulawayo, the chief city of Matabeleland.

Welshman Ncube was Youth Chairman of ZAPU, and Gibson Sipanda was its Secretary for Welfare. Both later served in Parliament for MDC.